# R get index of letters

Tags: r

I'm a noob with R. I want the alphabet index of each letter in a word. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, since the individual command works perfectly...

```
word <- "helloworld"
l <- numeric(nchar(word))
for (i in 0:nchar(word)) {
  l[i] <- match(substr(word,i,i+1), letters)
}
l
```

returns a weird `[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  4`

when `match(substr(word,0,1), letters)` returns the appropriate `[1] 8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is two fold.

First R indices start at 1 so when i = 0, l[i] is undefined.

Second, it doesn't just pull off a single letter at a time

```
i = 1
substr(word,i,i+1)
[1] "he"
```

A different approach

```
setNames(1:26, letters)[ strsplit("hello", NULL )[[1]] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error lies in the `i+1`: you are getting two character strings and so no match is found. Use `substring` which is vectorized:

```
match(substring(word,1:nchar(word),1:nchar(word)),letters)
#[1]  8  5 12 12 15 23 15 18 12  4
```

Another (nerdy) way is to get the offset of the ASCII value of each character to the value of the char `a`:

```
as.integer(charToRaw(word))-as.integer(charToRaw("a"))+1
#[1]  8  5 12 12 15 23 15 18 12  4
```

Answer (score 0):

You tested the only constellation that could work...

- vectors start counting with 1 in R, your loop would go from 1 to
  nchar(word)
- have a look at ?substr. You have to define start and
  stop, therefore you have to use substr(word, i, i)

But you don't have to use a loop here. as Richard Telford suggested, you can transform your string into a character-vector. Then you match every element of this vector to the letters vector

```
lapply(strsplit(word, ""), match, letters)
```